# How to free memory allocated by external C libraries interfacing with Cython module where the memory is ultimately returned to a Python process?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, cython

I am brand new to Cython, but basically I have this application that needs significant performance increases, and so my team and I are trying to rewrite our bottlenecks in Cython and in C.

For the slowest part of our application, I wrote some C code that gets compiled into a library and `cdef extern` imported into a Cython module, which I believe is a `.pyx` file. Essentially, the code in the `pyx` file is basically just a wrapper that returns calls to the C library functions. Finally, there is a Python process (the main application) that imports all of the functions defined in the `pyx` file and uses these results.

I believe I have a memory leak because in the C code, the results that I need to pass to the Python process are at times dynamically allocated. My issue is that I don't know how to free this memory once the Python process has made use of it.

**Example Python Code**

```py
from examplecython import *

def foo(data):
    context = data.context
    value = call_pyx_function(context, data)
    return value

def bar(results):
    for data in results:
        res = foo(data)
        do_something_with_res(res)
        # I want to free here
```

**Example Cython Code**

```
cdef extern from "my_lib.h"
    char * my_function(const char * context, int data)

def call_pyx_function(context: bytes, int x):
    return my_function(context, x)
```

**Example C Code**

```c
#define BUFSIZE 256

char *
my_function(const char * context, int x) {
    char * retbuf;
    int res;

    retbuf = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(char));

    res = do_some_math(x, context);

    int length = snprintf(retbuf, BUFSIZE, "%d", res);
    if (length >= BUFSIZE) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return retbuf;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how and where I can free this memory, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You wrote a function that returns allocated memory. Write also a function that frees that memory. Export said function to Python too. Now you can wrap everything in a Python class with a finalizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly import `free` from `libc.stdlib`:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport free

def bar(results):
    for data in results:
        res = foo(data)
        try:
            do_something_with_res(res)
        finally:
            free(res)
```

(Note you need the `try/finally` because you want it to be freed even if something throws an exception)

You can make this easier with a context manager or a wrapper that deletes in `__del__` / `__dealloc__`:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def freeing(res):
    try:
        yield res
    finally:
        free(res)

def bar(results):
    for data in results:
        with freeing(foo(data)) as res:
            do_something_with_res(res)
```

Or (Might get freed much later, probably slower, but (almost) guaranteed to be freed eventually)

```
# (in pyx file)
cdef class MallocedResource:
    cdef void* res;

    def __init__(self, res):
        # Note: This "steals" res. Don't free `res`
        # as it is freed when this class's storage is freed
        self.res = <void *>res

    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(self.res)

def call_pyx_function(context: bytes, int x):
    return MallocedResouce(my_function(context, x))

# No need to change python code, so you can't forget to use try/finally.
```

Comment: I really appreciate the effort put into this answer. I believe it would work for my case, but I like the idea of keeping Cython code separated from my Python code, so I'm going to try the suggestion provided by @n.m. - If that doesn't work, I'll give this a try. Part of my hesistation is not having a strong grasp on decorators. Would you be willing to explain the intention of `@contextlib.contextmanager` a bit more?

Comment: @pickle This is essentially the same as what @n.m.'s answer would have been, except it directly imports `free` from the C stdlib instead of creating a wrapper in C code and importing that (You can `cimport` in the pyx file). As for `@contextlib.contextmanager`, it basically converts the function into something that can be used in `with` (After the `with` block ends, `free` is called, much cleaner than `try/finally: free`).

Comment: Just wanted to correct the answer: [There is no `__del__()` method for extension types.](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#finalization-method-dealloc)

Comment: @ArdaAytekin Good catch. In this case, it's a simple fix to just renaming the method to `__dealloc__`. Thanks

Comment: @Artyer Yes, indeed. Please note also that `__cinit__()` is the initializer for C-related memory management (the documentation gives more info on the subtleties). I just came across this post when searching for another issue, and noticed your response. Otherwise, I do agree that it is a nice answer that also dwells on the context manager. Btw, one small typo still exists in the explanation: `__del__` (not the code excerpt).

Comment: And, as a side note, I would rather have the corresponding `free` function at the C-side (since @pickle and their team are already writing that C library). I would be hesitant to call `free` from within Cython, as the underlying C-API could have used `new`/`delete` from C++, instead. Sorry for chiming in like this.

Comment: No need to apologize! The commentary is certainly welcome. Are you hesitant because you're concerned that the memory will be silently freed? This is what end up happening to my Cython module so that I could use the string being passed up (https://gist.github.com/schmidtvl/e534b187bc68ed678e65dbec4731e305#file-cython_mod-pyx). It felt messy to make a call from the main Python application to get the memory freed on the C side.